# Jquery function in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination, getuikit

Using Uikit and its pagination I need to use this function to change page:

```
$('[data-uk-pagination]').on('uk-select-page', function(e, pageIndex){
            console.log("page " + pageIndex);
        });
```

But it seems that AngularJs not consider that and don't fires the event. If I click on a page number I can't display the `console.log. Is there any other way to do that?

This is the Html part:

```
<ul class="uk-pagination" data-uk-pagination="{items:{{itemsPagination}}, itemsOnPage:{{itemsOnPage}}}"></ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In docs it looks like:

```
$('[data-uk-pagination]').on('select.uk.pagination', function(e, pageIndex){
    alert('You have selected page: ' + (pageIndex+1));
});
```

[Docs](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/pagination-js.html)

Comment: Ok, that's correct, thanks! But it works only if i put this code inside a function called in a ng-click like: 

<ul class="uk-pagination" ng-click="nextPageFunction()" data-uk-pagination="{items:{{itemsPagination}}, itemsOnPage:{{itemsOnPage}}}"></ul>

but it's not correct. And it works only on second click of the page number. If i don't use the ng-click function not works